# Counting occurrences of Regex Matches in Python

Tags: python, regex, sorting, logging, counting

I have a log checker that is using regex to find the IP from lines in a logfile.
I want to find the lines, and count the total occurrences of those same lines, matched via IP

The goal is to generate statistics from the events, based on their IP.
example:

```
WARNING - 192.168.1.1 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 192.168.1.5 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 192.168.1.1 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 192.168.1.5 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 192.168.1.1 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 10.1.1.1 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 10.72.3.1 TIMING OUT    

192.168.1.1 - 3 EVENTS    
192.168.1.5 - 2 EVENTS    
10.1.1.1 - 1 EVENT    
10.72.3.1 - 1 EVENT
```

So on and so forth. I'm a python novice so I'm still learning what is best suitable for this purpose. As of this moment, I have the log file open, perform a for loop using the regex pattern to find the IP's in each line but from there I'm a bit lost. Cheers.

Comment: Just use a dictionary with the key being the IP address and increment the value every time you encounter each IP address.

Comment: @Nick cheers. Can you clarify - using a dictionary would I have explicitly define each IP address I need to log? With the log I'm potentially looking at over 50-100 different addresses.

Comment: no, you can use a variable as the key, and use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.defaultdict) to save worrying about undefined indexes e.g. https://rextester.com/CPP47999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a modified variant of my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64220148/6632736.

It is assumed that the log is in a file, which is read line by line.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re

def increment(ips: dict, line: str):
    match = re.match(r'^.+?\s+-\s+(?P<ip>\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})\s.*$', line)
    if match:
        ip = match.group('ip')
        if not ip in ips:
            ips[ip] = 0
        ips[ip] += 1

def parse_log_file(log: str) -> dict:
    ips = dict()
    with open(log, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            increment(ips, line)
    return ips

# log is the path to the log file:
for key, value in parse_log_file(log).items():
    print(key, ":", value)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count occurrences of a string pattern in a file and count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64220148/6632736).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much for this I appreciate all your responses :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `re.findall` here to capture all IP address events, then use a map to tally the number of occurrences:

```
inp = """WARNING - 192.168.1.1 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 192.168.1.5 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 192.168.1.1 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 192.168.1.5 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 192.168.1.1 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 10.1.1.1 TIMING OUT    
WARNING - 10.72.3.1 TIMING OUT"""

matches = re.findall(r'\bWARNING - (\b\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b)', inp)
d = {}

for elem in matches:
    try:
        val = d.get(elem) or 0
        d[elem] = val + 1
    except KeyError:
        d[elem] = d[elem]

print(d)
```

This prints:

```
{'10.1.1.1': 1, '192.168.1.5': 2, '10.72.3.1': 1, '192.168.1.1': 3}
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you didn't use `Counter` to do this?

Comment: My answer assumes that you already have the entire log text in a Python string.  If, on the other hand, you are reading the log file line by line, then instead you might start off with just a map and count this way.

Comment: `from collections import Counter    d = Counter(matches)`